# make Traefik route to a service on the same machine at a different port

Tags: traefik

I have a service(`myapp`) running on a node at port `5678`. I'm running Traefik on the same node(e.g. `myip`). How do I make Traefik route any requests to `http://myip/myapp` to the `myapp` service running at port `5678`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Traefik 2.x you can use redirectRegex in  middlewares:

```
middlewares:
    cleanerRegex:
         redirectRegex:   # <== this is it!
             regex: "^http?://example.com/myapp"
             replacement: "https://example.com:5678/"
[...]
```